# Guidance with refactoring issue

Tags: c#, refactoring

I have a couple of methods, 10 to be exact.
All of them have the same return type and accept the same params like so

public string GenerateDataForABC(List modelList, Student student)

Except for some customization they all pretty much do the same thing, i.e., return a string.

For example the method GenerateDataForDEF will have a unique code like so:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("STUDENT_NUMBER");
sb.Append("\tCALLBACK_NUMBER");
sb.Append("\tSPECIALINSTRUCTIONS");
...
```

So that one creates a heading for a tab separated file.
And then there will be a for loop that will have code like so:

```
foreach (Model model in modelList)
{
string sstudentNumber = "789";

sb.Append("\t");
sb.Append("\t");//SPECIALINSTRUCTIONS
sb.Append("\t" + model.ExamNumber);

...
}
```

The foreach is common in all the methods the only difference being the properties used from the Model object.
So one method may use all the properties, the other might use only 5.

Currently, as mentioned in the begining, there are seperate methods and the properites are used as per those methods requirement.

As I see it there are two problems to solve here:

1. The custom sections in each method. How to handle that?
2. The foreach. Is there an alternate?

I tried putting the required properties of the model in an xml and then to build the model for each method assigning only the required properties. That seems to work but solves only one part of the puzzle.

Any clue or direction is appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I've not misunderstood the overall question, one solution is a single method that takes a string for use with `String.Format()`:

```
private string GenerateData(string outputFormat, List modelList, Student student) {

  foreach (Model model in modelList)
  {
    sb.Append(String.Format(outputForm, model.ExamNumber, model.ExamDate, ...);
  }
}
```

Your specific methods could then be rewritten as:

```
public string GenerateDataForExamNumber(List modelList, Student student) {
  return GenerateData ("\t\tExam Number: {0}", modelList, student);
}
```

and

```
public string GenerateDataForExamDate(List modelList, Student student) {
  return GenerateData ("\t\tExam Date: {1}", modelList, student);
}
```

with possibly an additional `options` object in event of their being further minor differences required between the outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you had a Heading class which, given a string, returned the appropriate heading string.

Sorry, this will be more java-ish than C#-ish, but I think you'll get the idea:

```
final public static String STUDENT_NUMBER = "Student Number";
final public static String CALLBACK_NUMBER = "Callback Number";
final public static String SPECIAL_INSTRUCTIONS = "Special Instructions";
// etc.

public String getHeading(String key) {
    if (key.equals(STUDENT_NUMBER) return STUDENT_NUMBER;
    // etc;
}
```

That would be simplified by using a Map, but it's straightforward.

Now say your Model, too, can return a String given the key:

```
public String getCell(String key) {
    if (key.equals(STUDENT_NUMBER) return StudentNumber;
    // etc.
}
```

Again, this could be improved, with a separate class to serve up the cell values, but that's a detail that doesn't really help explain, so I'll leave it out of the code.

Now, take a list or array of headings:

```
final String[] columns = {STUDENT_NUMBER, CALLBACK_NUMBER, SPECIAL_INSTRUCTIONS};
```

And pass that list to a new method:

```
public String makeTable(Heading heading, Model[] models, String[] columns) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String column: columns) {
        sb.Append(heading.getHeading(column).Append("\t");
    }
    for (Model model: models) {
        for (String column: columns) {
            sb.Append(model.getCell(column).Append("\t");
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

That should about do it.  You can worry about the trailing tabs of course, but basically with this we have generalized the solution.